# Uninstall Apps on tvOS Simulator

Tags: simulator, tvos

How can i uninstall apps from tvOS simulator?

I already tried to long press the icon, but no "close button" appears.

I know, this is a Beta version, maybe in future they'll implement something like iOS.
Thank you.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Method 1**

From Home Screen:

```
Settings->General->Manage Storage
```

And here you can uninstall your apps.

**Method 2**

As suggested Jess.
Long press on the remote. 
Apps start to wiggle. Hit the play/pause button. 
You will be presented with a delete dialog.

Answer (score 10):

Long press on the remote. Apps start to wiggle. Hit the play/pause button. You will be presented with a delete dialog.

Answer (score 5):

1. Long press on the Return key until the app wiggles.
2. Press the space bar to show the delete confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Long press the TV remote or Simulator remote then App start wiggle, showing pop-up for options `Tap play/pause button for options`
Now you choose your options(Delete)

or go with this easy way

`Settings->General->Manage Storage`

[image]